# Comfirmation of inputs before send get requests in a form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I wonder how I can confirm the email is having a @ sign using javascript before submitting to signUp.php?

```
<form action='signUp.php'>
    <input type='text' name='email'>
    <input type='text' name='firstName'>
    <button value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this `javascript`:

```
/@/.test(document.forms[0].email.value)
```

in your form:

```
<button value='submit' onclick='javascript: if (/@/.test(document.forms[0].email.value) == true) { document.forms[0].submit(); } else { return; }' />
```

I'd better prefer to use something like following:

HTML:

```
<form action='signUp.php' id='theform'>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email'>
    <input type='text' name='firstName'>
    <button value='submit' onclick='javascript: checkform(); return;'>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var checkform = function() {
  var theform = document.getElementById('theform');
  if (is_email(document.getElementById('email').value))) {
    theform.submit();
  }
  return;
}
var is_email = function(val) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum|travel)$/.test(val)
}
```

`^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum|travel)$` is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) that checks is a value is a valid email address string. In your question you've asked just to test an existence of `@` in your string, but, hey! `not@email` will be matched! You certainly don't want to allow strings like that to be treated as valid email strings.

Basicly, you want to check your form data before form submit action. So you can do either:

- `<form onsubmit='if (!checkform()) reutrn;'>`
  or
- `<input type='submit' onclick='checkform()' />`

In `checkform` function you validate fields data and if validation is passed, you call `submit` method on html form object and you return `false` or nothing (e.g. `return;`) otherwise.

You should also learn how to use `regular expressions` within `javascript` [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: Hi! Do you also know how I can prevent a submit when I have a button inside a form?  I have a cancel button and it submits the form everytime I click on it?

Comment: @Woho87 - you really should post another question.. but anyway... by default, [buttons](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) are submit buttons. Give it a type of `button` or use `<input type="button"...>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
// it's valid so do something
}
else {
// it's not valid so do something else
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that filter_var() is only available in php 5.2+

Comment: this answer is not correct. It means that I have already submitted it to signUp.php

Comment: then you shouldn't of put the *php* tag in the question. I have removed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the submit event on the form, check the email value, and conditionally allow or deny the form to post.  Using jQuery (because..why would you not?) you'd do something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('form').get(0).submit(function(event)
    {
        var email = $(this).find('input[name=email]').val();
        if (email.match(/.+?@.+/) == false)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I love this jQuery stuff. You realise that `$(this).find('input[name=email]').val();` is simply `this.email.value`. But that uses direct property access and saves about a zillion function calls, so why would anyone do that? ;-)

Comment: Because it removes browser inconsistencies /:

Comment: Name **any** browser inconsistency removed by the above code when getting the value of an input element. Just one will do.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `type="email"` and a HTML5 forms emulation for older browsers.
http://thecssninja.com/javascript/H5F
https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F

```
<input type='email' name='email'>
```

This not only validates that it contains a `@`, but also verifies a correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

You must validate on the server, but you can add some user convenience by checking on the client first:

```
function checkEmail(el) {
  return /@/.test(el.value);
}
```

or a little more friendly:

```
function checkEmail(el) {
  if (!/@/.test(el.value)) {
    alert('Your e-mail address doesn\'t have an "@"' +
          ' sign, please add one');
    return false;
  }
}
```

And in the page:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return checkEmail(this.email);" ...>
```